# - Have you already finished your essay? - No, I will ___ it by this Thursday

Tags: perfect-aspect

In an online placement test that is, frankly, not the best of the best, this sentence is provided with a gap to be filled:

> - Have you already finished your essay? - No, I will ___ it by this Thursday

The correct answer is, obviously, "have finished", but I wonder: **Why is "finish" (just Future Simple) listed as incorrect?**

Comment: Both "have finished" and "finish"  are correct. In addition, using "already" in the question is unnecessary and a bit unusual: it's the sort of thing that a a German would say. Where did you see this question?

Comment: *Not the best of the best?* It's obviously ***total garbage**!* Ignore it!

Comment: @JavaLatte [In an awful test](https://onlinetestpad.com/ru/testresult/6889-placement-test?res=hkbgyfmv25a7w). I'd say this as "Have you finished your essay (yet)?" -- "No, I'll do it by X". Apparently, it was made by a poorly-educated Russian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JavaLatte wrote in comments either *have finished* or *finish* is fine here. As you also mentioned in a comment the question would sound more natural as *Have you finished your essay yet?* And *I will do it by Thursday* would be an equally good response.

Answer (score 1):

Both *finish* and *have finished* are fine, but notice that the meaning is slightly different.

A comment was made about *already* being redundant.  This is not true.  *Already* is not redundant.